# Identity is not persistent in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

I am using the below code

```
 var authenticationManager = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
 var claims = new List<Claim>();
 claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "username"));
 claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "username@gmail.com"));
 var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
 authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true }, userIdentity);
 ClaimsPrincipal principal2 = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);
 System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal2;
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User = principal2;
 var test = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated; //this resolves to true here 
 return RedirectToAction("List"); // redirecting to action
```

Now after adding claims details, I am redirecting to an action. When its redirected, the `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` becomes false.

```
public ActionResult List()
{
      var claimsIdentity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
      var test = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

     //this resolves to false here
     string email = claimsIdentity?.FindFirst(c => c.Type == System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
         //this is null
}
```

Comment: This may be caused by the redirect. I already had some cases where the thread aborded because I was redirecting the user after the action. Maybe your could try to not redirect the user automatically and open the page manually, where you test the authentication.